# Size on disk smaller than actual size

Tags: macos, filesystem, apfs

I have Bitwarden on my machine and looked at the reported file size, wich is `423,6MB`. The downloaded file is much smaller, also the reported size on disk is much smaller too with `176,5MB`

[image]

I expected if anything that the size on disk would always be larger due to block size, but not smaller. How can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HFS+ (from 10.6 on) and APFS [have support for transparent compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_File_System#Compression). This is applied automatically to the OS, App Store apps, and anything installed via pkg files.

Comment: You can get a list of the compressed files by using the command `find /Applications/Bitwarden.app -type f -flags +compressed -exec ls -ldO {} +`. You can get a list of the files which are not compressed by using the command `find /Applications/Bitwarden.app -type f -flags +nocompressed -exec ls -ldO {} +`.